# What are freezes in the Trusty Tahr release schedule?

Tags: freeze

After looking at this website: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule
I noticed that there are freezes, like feature freeze and user interface freeze. Can someone explain to me what those mean? Will that affect my computer with Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Freezes* are just deadlines that mark partials milestones in the road map to get the final release. Ej.

[Feature Freeze](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FeatureFreeze): At this point we stop introducing new features, packages, and APIs, and concentrate on fixing bugs in the development release.

[User Interface Freeze](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UserInterfaceFreeze): The user interface must be stabilized at some point, so that documentation writers and translators can work on a fixed target that doesn't obsolete screenshots or documentation.

[Here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) you can get cd images that even not finals, meet those partial milestones. I mean, if you retrieve a cd image of the daily build March 13th you must expect a system that will not have changes in UI compared with the final release, apart the existence of some [exceptions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FreezeExceptionProcess).